# Is there a link between SASP and fibrosis?

Tags: cell-biology, senescence, inflammation

1/ Fibrosis: Fibrosis is the formation of excessive fibrous connective tissue in an organ or tissue during a reparative process.

2/ SASP: SASP is the accumulation of molecules and senescent cells in tissue, that triggers "dead" parts in the body

Is there a link between these two phenomenon? I'm specially thinking about the fact that SASP in an organ would not be able to replicate and recreate parenchymal tissue, leaving the place to connective tissue to replicate: This would end in fibrosis?

**Question**: Is SASP one of the factors leading to fibrosis?